# GoldenGate 19c integrated extract start error OGG-02030 Failed to set logmining server parameters back to default val

Tags: database, oracle, replication

I`ve try to start integrated Extract:

```
REGISTER EXTRACT EXTR_R DATABASE
ADD EXTRACT EXTR_R, INTEGRATED TRANLOG, begin now
ADD EXTTRAIL ./dirdat/lt, EXTRACT EXTR_R
START EXTRACT EXTR_R
```

with param file:

```
Extract EXTR_R
USERIDALIAS GGUSERSRC
exttrail ./dirdat/lt
LOGALLSUPCOLS
UPDATERECORDFORMAT COMPACT
STATOPTIONS RESETREPORTSTATS
REPORT at 15:00
REPORTROLLOVER AT 15:00
REPORTCOUNT EVERY 60 SECONDS, RATE  
Table hr.*;
```

and after start I get error:

```
INFO    OGG-06618  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, extr_r.prm:  Database DBG125 Platform: Linux x86 64-bit.
ERROR   OGG-02030  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, extr_r.prm:  Failed to set logmining server parameters back to default values.
ERROR   OGG-02042  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, extr_r.prm:  OCI Error 23,605.
ERROR   OGG-01668  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, extr_r.prm:  PROCESS ABENDING.
```

What were the problem parameters? How it can be fixed?
Thanks, a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

It is bug in Standard Edition version - https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2521793_1.html

Patch fixes the problem.